# Solving $Ax = \lambda x$ for $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is it possible to solve $Ax = \lambda x$ for the matrix $A$? Im having a problem where i have a vector $v = (-2, 1)$ and i would need to find $A$ from $Av = 2v$. All help would be appreciated.

Comment: I mean, why not just $A=\lambda I$? It is one of many solutions.

Comment: There is no unique solution. The trivial one is $A=2I$, where $I$ is the 2x2 identity matrix

Comment: There are infinite linear transformations that have 2 as an eigenvalue

Comment: To completely specify a $2 \times 2$ matrix, you need to specify how it maps the elements of a basis for $\mathbb R^2$. You have only specified how it maps a single element of $\mathbb R^2$. If you specify what it does to a second element that is linearly independent of $v$, then that will completely specify $A$. The best you can say with the given information is that if $a_1$ and $a_2$ are the columns of $A$, then $-2a_1 + a_2 = 2v$, which (taken row by row) yields two equations in four unknowns.